# Laravel 5.2 foreign key errors

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I have created two migrations with the Jeffrey Way generators for Laravel 5. Namely: `php artisan make:migrate:schema create_roles_table --schema='name:string, description:text'` and `php artisan make:migrate:pivot user role`.

Now, my MySQL database is defaulted to `InnoDB`, which I've read should be. I also moved the foreign key setup to `Schema::table()` instead of `Schema::create('role_user')`. There shouldn't be anything wrong with my migrations, yet they error out with: `General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table role_user add constraint role_user_user_id_foreign foreign key (user_id) references user (id) on delete cascade)`.

```
Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->primary(['role_id', 'user_id']);
        });

        Schema::table('role_user', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('role')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

[image]

I have called `$table->engine = 'InnoDB';` in every migration. Also have I set all `id` columns to `unsigned`, even though they were like that already. I am clueless, who helps me out..

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have already migrated the tables users and roles. Otherwise you will not be able to create a foreign key. Check your migration order as well. If you are migrating this one before the users and roles it will fail.

Comment: The order seems to be right:
- Users
- Roles
- Role_User pivot table
- Foreign keys.

I also dropped all tables and reran all migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently this was a huge typo. `user` instead of `users`, for example. I had hoped Laravel would get that right, but unfortunately Laravel and I as well didn't.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to your SQL engine, check your engine (mariadb, mysql, ...)

And then read the documentation from your engine regarding foreign keys.

---

**Quick solution** 
Remove the `onDelete('cascade')` and run the migration.
You can add it manually from phpMyAdmin later on